# jquery not selector is not working properly

Tags: jquery

I know there were some topics with similar issue, but I can't find solution to fix my problem.
I've got 7 `a` alements. They've got `nav-link`, `item-element` classes, and one of them `active` class also.

I have a script which will do some method if inactive element will be clicked.
My script:

```
$('a.nav-link.item-element').not('.active').click(function () {    
    console.log(result);
});
```

My problem is that even if I click active element, the script is doing his job, so the `not` property is not working, but if I will paste first select line to the console, it's ok:

[image]

So summarizing: **selector `not` is working when I check it in a console, but it doesn't work when I'm clicking on the element**.

Anyone know what can be the problem?

##HTML

I made raw html just to show you - I know that's not pretty, but it's just for test:

````
<a class="nav-link item-element" href="#" id="test-element" data-toggle="pill" role="tab" aria-selected="false">element2</a>
<a class="nav-link item-element" href="#" id="test-element" data-toggle="pill" role="tab" aria-selected="false">element3</a>
<a class="nav-link item-element" href="#" id="test-element" data-toggle="pill" role="tab" aria-selected="false">element4</a>
<a class="nav-link item-element" href="#" id="test-element" data-toggle="pill" role="tab" aria-selected="false">element5</a>
<a class="nav-link item-element" href="#" id="test-element" data-toggle="pill" role="tab" aria-selected="false">element6</a>
<a class="nav-link item-element" href="#" id="test-element" data-toggle="pill" role="tab" aria-selected="false">element7</a>```
````

Comment: We also need to see the HTML so we can create a working example of the issue

Comment: use: `$(document).on('click', 'a.nav-link.item-element:not(.active)', function(){})` as you are probably manipulating dom

Comment: John your solution is working, thanks! Maybe post a comment to accept your answer. Anyway can you describe why with ```$(document)``` it's working?

Comment: It's because you add the `active` class at runtime. It's not on the elements when the DOM loads and the event handler is bound. John's suggestion works because it's a delegated event handler